# Drawing lines and deleting lines

Tags: java, graphics2d, lines

I am trying to create a program that allows the user to drag and draw lines and also delete the lines after it have been drawn. Is there any ways i can do it? I have the code that draws the line but i am not sure how i could delete the lines after i have drawn it. Im looking to click any of the lines drawn and delete it with the delete button.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Drawing { 
public Drawing() { 
    JFrame jf=new JFrame("Free Hand Drawing Example");

    Board draw=new Board();     
    jf.add(draw);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.setSize(600,500);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String a[]){
    new Drawing();
}
}

class Board extends JPanel implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener {
 ArrayList<pts> list = new ArrayList<pts>();
 Point start,end;

 public Board() {
 start=null;  /*Initializing*/
 end=null;

//this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
this.addMouseListener(this);
this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
super.paint(g2);
//g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
for (pts p : list)
    g.drawLine((int)p.getStart().getX(), (int)p.getStart().getY(),    (int)p.getEnd().getX(), (int)p.getEnd().getY());

if(start!=null)
{
    g.drawLine(start.x,start.y,end.x,end.y);
}
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
start = me.getPoint();  

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
end = me.getPoint();
pts pt = new pts(start,end);
list.add(pt);
repaint();
for(pts p : list)
{
    System.out.println(p.getStart()+""+p.getEnd());
}
start = null;
end = null;
}
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
end = me.getPoint();
repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {}
 }

class pts{

Point start = null;
Point end = null;


public pts(Point start, Point end){
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;      
}

public Point getStart(){
    return this.start;
}

public Point getEnd(){
    return this.end;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one way to go about this, but one simple approach would be to add a 'delete' button with an `ActionListener` that clears out the list of points you have when the button is pressed.  You could also associate the clearing action with something like a `MouseDragged` event, but that doesn't seem very user friendly.

**UPDATE**:
So, to delete the line when the user clicks on it, you could use a simple function like this one:

```
public boolean intersects(Point linePoint1, 
                          Point linePoint2, 
                          Point usersClickPoint) {
    return new Line2D.Float(linePoint1, linePoint2).
        ptLineDist(usersClickPoint) <= 0.01;//some margin of error
}
```

in your `MousePressed` method.

**Side Note:** The way you've chosen to interpret the mouse events is a bit strange.  You record the first point on `MousePressed`, and the second one on `MouseReleased`.  Why not use `MouseClicked` and simply keep track of the first and second clicks when drawing the line?

Comment: hi, sorry i forgot to add in that i am trying to click on the line and delete the line. is there any approach for this?

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply. The reason why i used the mouse pressed and mouse release is because i want to have a line drawn by the dragging and releasing the mouse.

Comment: @Amir If you want to "preview" the line drawn on `MouseDragged`, intercepting `MouseClick` for line creation might be a bad idea...

Comment: Sure, but he never said anything about previewing.  I can think of many reasons why doing something is a bad idea once an intention is made clear.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a Line object for each line your user draws and have the object store the locations on the screen where the line is drawn. Then when in delete mode, have an onClickListener that will select a line based upon the coordinates of the click matching up to a point contained in a line. Then just delete the line (probably could redraw using the same endpoints but with the pen set to the background color). There would need to be some logic for the possible case where lines intersect and you don't want to delete a portion of the other line, but that could be solved fairly easily. Keep in mind, I'm not a big graphics programmer. This is just my idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. was thinking of this but if i was to use it as a connector between 2 objects that can be drag around, im not sure if it applies well.